# Object are losing their methods inside this function

Tags: javascript, methods

First of all, all variables name are in Italian so I hope it's not a huge problem. Anyway I'm making a web app to keep track of all my marks at school in all subjects, to do this I wanted to try using Objects. I created 3 objects:
-Voto (mark in english): only has some variables in it,no methods.
-Materia (subject in english): has some variables, an array of 'Voto' objects and a few methods such as aggiungiVoto ( addMark ) or ottieniMedia ( getAverageMark )
-Registro ( school register ): similiar to Materia, has some variables, some methods and an array of 'Materia' objects
Problem is that in some cases if I call a method of an object it says 'function is not declared' but it's there and if I use the console to create an identical object to the one which gave the error I can find the method and it works. Strangely though, all the variables are there, only methods are missing. An example is this function which is supposed to take a Registro object and create some HTML elements representing all the subject, which should show every subject name with their average mark.

```
function MostraRegistro(reg) {
// I create all HTML object in a DIV with id main
var toAppend = "";
main = "#main";
$(main).html("");
for (i = 0; i < reg.materie.length; i++) {
    toAppend = "";
    toAppend += "<div id='DisplayDiv_" + reg.materie[i].nome + "' >";
    toAppend += "<div class='materia' onclick='MostraMateria(" + i + ");'>";
// The line where it gives the error, where I call ottieniMedia()
    toAppend += "<text class='TestoMaterie'>" + reg.materie[i].nome + "  Media:" + String(reg.materie[i].ottieniMedia()) + "</text'></div>";

    toAppend += "<div class='materiaPlus' onclick='Menu_AggiungiVoto(" + String(i) + ");' >AGGIUNGI VOTO</div>";
    toAppend += "</div>";
    $(main).append(toAppend);
}
```

}

Something I noticed is that if I create an object 'Materia' but I don't assign it to a variable it doesn't have my methods, I guess this is my problem since when I add a new subject/school register I simply do

```
materie.push(new Materia(subjectname) );
```

But I really don't know how to solve this and I couldn't find anything related on Google

```
var Voto = function (voto, tipo, data, commento,ignora) {
    this.voto = voto;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.data = data;
    this.commento = commento;
    if (ignora === undefined) {
        this.ignora = false;
    }
    else {
        this.ignora = ignora;
    }
};
var Materia = function (nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.votiPresenti = 0;
    this.voti = new Array();
}
Materia.prototype.aggiungiVoto = function (voto, tipo, data, commento) {
this.votiPresenti++;
this.voti.push(new Voto(voto, tipo, data, commento));
};
Materia.prototype.ottieniMedia = function () {
    if (this.votiPresenti == 0)
        return "Vuoto";
    else {
        var media = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < this.votiPresenti; i++) {
            if (!this.voti[i].ignora) {
                media += parseFloat(this.voti[i].voto);
            }
        }
        return (media / this.votiPresenti);
    }
};
var Registro = function(nome,annoRegistro){
    this.materie = new Array();
    this.materiePresenti = 0;
    this.annoRegistro = annoRegistro;
    this.nome = nome;
};
Registro.prototype.aggiungiMateria = function(nome){
    this.materiePresenti++;
    this.materie.push(new Materia(nome));
};
```

Comment: could you narrow down the problem to the place where you have an error and post the particular code here?

Comment: Can you post some code related to `Materia` function and its prototype? Show us how methods are declared.

Comment: I added how I declared the objects and their methods

Comment: Hmm, I don't say anything wrong. Where is the `Registro` object created? Do you, by any chance, do some sort of (de)serialization? Do you use `JSON.parse/JSON.stringify` for anything related?

Comment: That was it! When I loaded a 'Registro' object I simply did array.push(JSON.parse(string) ) without thinking that I didn't create an object 'Materia' but simply an empty object with the same properties of a 'Materia' object. Thank you so much,I spent 2 days thinking about it and I wasn't even looking at the right place